# Strange linker error when using Boost Interprocess 1.60 release build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, boost-interprocess

We have some code using Boost Interprocess for managed shared memory. It links fine against our debug build of Boost 1.60, and it links against our release build of Boost 1.55, but when linking against our release build of Boost 1.60, I get these two errors:

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall boost::container::container_detail::has_member_function_named_construct<class boost::container::new_allocator<char> >::BaseMixin::construct(void)" (?construct_at_BaseMixin@?$has_member_function_named_construct_at_V?$new_allocator_at_D@container_at_boost@@@container_detail_at_container@boost@@QAEXXZ)`

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall boost::container::container_detail::has_member_function_named_construct<class boost::container::new_allocator<struct boost::container::container_detail::tree_node<struct std::pair<class boost::container::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class boost::container::new_allocator<char> > const ,struct boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::ref_count_ptr>,void *,0,1> > >::BaseMixin::construct(void)" (?construct_at_BaseMixin@?$has_member_function_named_construct_at_V?$new_allocator_at_U?$tree_node_at_U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string_at_DU?$char_traits_at_D@std@@V?$new_allocator_at_D@container_at_boost@@@container_at_boost@@Uref_count_ptr_at_ipcdetail@interprocess_at_3@@std@@PAX$0A@$00_at_container_detail_at_container@boost@@@container_at_boost@@@container_detail_at_container@boost@@QAEXXZ)`

Googling around I've found [this](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2015/12/85504.php) report on the Boost mailing list, but there's no resolution there.

The compiler is Visual Studio 2010, and the libraries are automatically brought in by Boost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that is something related with the precompiled headers configuration in the project file. In my case I could set the option to not using precompiled headers and it worked fine.
There is a thread here to get into more details about it  [here](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2015/12/85388.php)